# Test kafka based backend application using the Confluent platform?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

how the functional testcases are written for backend applications which is based on pub-sub model?
Any example please?

I tried using confluent platform to test kafka producer & consumers but I wasn’t able to configure topic in confluent.

Answer (score 0):

Confluent Platform is not a requirement for Spring-Kafka testing. I suggest you follow the Spring docs on how to test your app, and start with the mocks for *unit testing* rather than actually needing any Kafka infrastructure.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#mock-cons-prod